# How to set post status to Delete?

Tags: posts

How do I add a post status option to delete the post instead of setting it to draft or pending or anything like that?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add more details? You may be interested in [wp_update_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)

Answer (score 1):

You can move the post to Trash before you save it or publish:

[image]

Or you can do it later, from the post list:

[image]

Later you can empty Trash or it will automatically delete everything from Trash what is older than a month.

Comment: Ah, good one. I automatically assumed the question was about code. :)

Comment: @montrealist, I'm not really sure. :) The question is too thin.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the post status to `trash`.

```
$post_id = 1; // change this to your post ID
$status = 'trash';
$current_post = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
$current_post['post_status'] = $status;
wp_update_post($current_post);
```

Got code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12518/8105).

Comment: So you can set post status to trash and it will move it to the trash?

Comment: It should, yes.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it ends up working for you. ;)